# Angular How to properly use a factory returned data

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-resource

I have a factory use `$resource` to make `HTTP` calls.
The factory code:

```
.factory('me', function($resource, API_URL) {
    var url = API_URL + 'api/me';
    return $resource(url);
})
```

I use it in a controller and I manage to display the data returned from factory in view like this:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, me) {
    $scope.data = me.get();
   console.log($scope.data);
})
```

View code to display this data was obiously like this:

```
<h3>{{data.displayName}}</h3>
```

when I took a look at my console I found that am getting the data but I also getting `$promise` and `$resolved` I had a feeling that am not doing it the way it meant to be and I made sure when I tried to use the same factory in different controller like this:

```
.controller('newItemCtrl', function($scope, me) {
var data = me.get();
console.log(data.displayName);
})
```

I got undefined.
My question again how it work in the first use and didn't in the second use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$resource.get()` does not immediately return data. Instead it returns an empty reference that is updated with the data once the data is returned from the server.

Instead of directly assigning the result of the `get()` to your scope variable, you should be using the success and error callbacks:

```
angular.module('foo').controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, me) {
   me.get(function (result) {
     $scope.data = result;
     console.log($scope.data);
   }, function (error) {
     // handle error here
   });
});
```

Comment: Because the data hasn't been returned from the server in that use, so `data.displayName` hasn't been defined. `data` is just an empty reference. You're getting lucky on the first use that data has been returned when you call `console.log`.

Comment: It's not about luck, the point is that the first console.log is being made on a reference, so you print the reference to that object even thought there is no data, but by the time you open it in console the data returns and the object is filled accordingly. In the second case you try to print a property which at the moment doesn't exist, since the object is empty.

Comment: am also still can't figure out how to use the data in the rest of the controller code, so i can send it in HTTP call to the server, i mean out of the function(result) scope

Comment: The $scope.data variable is available anywhere in the controller.

Comment: @getOffMyLawn `console.log` does not wait for the console to be opened to write the object state. He says he can see his data in the first log statement, so it would have to be returned when `console.log` is called. If the object is empty when `console.log` is called it prints an empty object. It doesn't go back and update it if the object changes.

Comment: True, when i console.log($scope.data.displayName); inside the scope i got the name correctly but out of the scope of the function i get undefined
but if logged the $scope.data i get all the data

Comment: @getOffMyLawn turns out I'm dumb. It actually does wait until the console is opened and the object is expanded to get the object state. So you are correct. I'm not sure how I've never run into this.

Answer (score 0):

It returns a promise, so you should use like that:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, me) {
    $scope.data = me.get(function(data) {
       $scope.data = data;
       console.log($scope.data);
    })
})
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource